# Loosing previous realm data when I do migration in android

Tags: android, realm

I am using 0.82.0 version of realm.I attempting to two new classes (which extends RealmObject) to existing schema.Created RealmConfiguration using application context,and getting a Realm instance using that configuration wherever needed.

My migration code is

```
public class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override
    public long execute(Realm realm, long version) {
        if(version == 0)
           version++;
        return version;
    }
}

public class RealmUtils  {

    private static RealmConfiguration config;

    public static void createRealmConfig(Context context) { 

        config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name("default.realm1")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new MyMigration())
                .build();
    }

    public static Realm getRealmInstance() { 

        return Realm.getInstance(config);
    }
}
```

Previously it was giving migrationNeededException, now exception is not coming but previous data is lost.

if i use any version >= 0.87.0, should i add all the tables in migrate() method or only new ones? I followed the example https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main ,still facing same problem.
any ideas please ??

Comment: What are the changes of models in your new version?

Comment: Adding two tables, not changing anything in existing tables.

Comment: Then just add the new ones should work~

Comment: How to add new tables in version 0.82.0 ?? Is execute() method body is enough or am I missing anything ?? I am getting exception                                              io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: The XYZ class is missing from the schema for this Realm. Here XYZ is new table.

Comment: Why don't you use the latest version? Since 0.86.0, a new migration API has been added which is easier to use. I think you have checked ttps://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main ? Doc here with some general information https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations . To add a new object, something like :`schema.create("XYZ").addField("field1", String.class)`. Please take a look at the migration related samples and docs please.